# How to set fixed size for inputfile text in adf

Tags: oracle-adf

I am using `inputFile` component to upload file. When i finish uploading the file, the input text field will *shrink* its size and change the size to adjust the file name. Is there any way to set a fix size for input text field?

Here is some part of the code:

```
<af:inputFile label="File" id="if1"   columns="25" inlineStyle="width:230px;"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `PanelLabelAndMessage` and set the `contentStyle` of that to *100px* for example.

Comment: +1 for this approach. Gives you much more flexibility in configuration and I'd say no drawback. Don't forget to set `simple=true` for input control to turn off default label.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<af:inputFile label="File" id="if1" columns="25" contentStyle="width:230px;"/>
```

instead. This will override your **content**'s properties.